# Pegar todos os dados de uma tabela HTML e inserir no banco de dados

Tags: php, sql, ajax, banco-de-dados, tabela-html

Tenho uma tabela editável em html, ao clicar em salvar, preciso pegar todos os dados da tabela, enviar por ajax para a pagina que faz o INSERT de todas as linhas no banco de dados.

Minha duvida seria:

1. Como pegar todas as linhas da tabela e enviar via ajax.
2. Como fazer o INSERT de todas essas linhas, já que podem ser 5, 6 ou mais linhas. Nunca um valor fixo.

**Estrutura da tabela HTML**

```
<tbody class="list_modificacao"><tr>
    <th scope="row">JOAO</th>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark luz">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua_campo">-</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <th scope="row">MARIA</th>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark luz">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua_campo">-</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <th scope="row">JOSE</th>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark luz">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua_campo">-</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Estrutura BD**

```
+------+-----+------+------------+
| NOME | LUZ | AGUA | AGUA_CAMPO |
+------+-----+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma simples com JQuery:

No front-end, você faz um loop e monta um array bidimensional para enviar pro back-end

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tbody class="list_modificacao"><tr>
    <th scope="row">JOAO</th>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark luz">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua_campo">-</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <th scope="row">MARIA</th>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark luz">a</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua">b</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua_campo">c</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <th scope="row">JOSE</th>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark luz">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua">-</td>
        <td class="text-center option_divisao bg-dark agua_campo">-</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

No back-end você faz mais ou menos a mesma coisa para criar o script SQL

```
<script>
//Todas th, vai servir para criar array dentro do array
var th = $('tbody th');
//Todas td
var td = $('tbody td');
//Array final que vai ser enviado por AJAX
var array = [];

//Monta o array
for(var i = 0; i < th.length; i++) {
  array[i] = [th[i].innerText, td[0].innerText, td[1].innerText, td[2].innerText];
}

//Chama o AJAX
$.ajax({
  url: 'teste.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {array: array}
})
.done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
</script>
<?php
//Armazena a variável que veio por post
$array = $_POST["array"];

//Monta a variável com o script SQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela() ";

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $sql .= "values(".$array[$i][0].", ".$array[$i][1].", ".$array[$i][2].", ".$array[$i][3]."),";
}

//Retira a última vírgula
$sql = trim($sql, ",");

//Mostra o SQL, no caso aqui você o executaria (mysqli_ ou PDO)
echo $sql;
?>
```